# Две cookie при работе с авторизацией в YII2

Tags: yii2, auth

Компонент session определн вот так

```
'session' => [
  'name' => 'MYCOOKIE',
  'class' => 'yii\redis\Session',
  'redis' => [
    'hostname' => 'remotehost',
    'port' => 6379,
    'database' => 1,
  ],
],
```

Когда клиент форму логина вводит логин и пароль, то вызываю

```
Yii::$app()->user->login($identity, 3600*24*30);
```

Зачем-то YII2 создает две куки MYCOOKIE and _identity. Первая живет сессию, а вторая как раз 3600*24*30. Но при закрытии браузера клиента разлогинивает.

Зачем нужна cookie _identity?

Comment: По идее она должна быть связана с галочкой `remember me`. Ведь даже в экшне `login` есть строчка `return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);` Но, возможно, что-то идет не так.

Comment: а что у вас прописано в конфиге? в `components` есть пункт `'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],`  ?